# If $f \in L^1 \cap L^p$, we can find constants $c,\lambda$ such that $||f||_1 \leq c m(A)^{\lambda}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to do the following exercise:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be in $L^1 \cap L^p$. Show that there exist constants $c>0$ and $\lambda \in (0,1) $ so that

(1) $|\int_A |f(x)| dx \leq c m(A)^{\lambda}$

for every Borel measureable set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

My approach:
I know that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the set ${(a,b):a,b \in \mathbb{R}}$.

This means that $A$ has the form $A=(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Which means that $c m(A)^{\lambda}=c (b-a)^{\lambda}$.

Since $f \in L^1$, we have $\int_A |f|d \mu<\infty$, and since $f \in L^p$, we have $\int_A |f|^p d \mu < \infty$.
I do not really know how to proceed.

Comment: Can $c$ depend on $f$? If so this is simple: By Holder's inequality, $\int 1_A |f|\le \|f||_p(\int (1_A)^{q})^{1/q}$ wheer $\frac 1  p+\frac 1 q=1$. Just take $c=\|f\|_p$ and $\lambda=\frac 1  q$.

Comment: @geetha290krm This is not specified. So I will assume it can depend on $f$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I don't know If I should open a new question, but does the reverse hold to. I.e. if $f$ is integrale and there exists constants $c, \lambda$ as above such that $\int_A|f(x)| dx \leq c m(A)^\lambda $, does this imply that $f \in L^p$ for some $p \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes, it does hold with $p=\frac 1 {1-\lambda}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you. I don't really see how you came up with $p=\frac{1}{1-\lambda}$. Could you maybe explain?